# Renaming first column to distinguish between startsites script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im looking for a way to convert the file as below called INPUT to OUTPUT. The file INPUT consists of columns consisting the unique ID, ID and the value. I would like to convert the ID to separated IDs based on the value as distinction. I tried some basic commands but could not manage to make it work for the main input file which is 20,000 rows and has 15,000 IDs.
Does anyone has some nice ideas/suggestions how to handle this problem?

```
       INPUT                OUTPUT      
unique  ID  VALUE       unique  ID  VALUE
A1  GENEA   10  ->  A1  GENEAp1 10
A2  GENEA   5   ->  A2  GENEAp2 5
A3  GENEA   2   ->  A3  GENEAp3 2
A4  GENEB   4   ->  A4  GENEBp4 4
A5  GENEB   5   ->  A5  GENEBp3 5
A6  GENEB   8   ->  A6  GENEBp2 8
A7  GENEB   70  ->  A7  GENEBp1 70
A8  GENEC   5   ->  A8  GENECp1 5
A9  GENED   50  ->  A9  GENEDp2 50
A10 GENED   10  ->  A10 GENEDp3 10
```

Preferably the numbering of p based on the value. With p1 with the highest value, p2 second highest etc.

Comment: Are you just trying to stick `p#` (with consecutive numbers per-ID) after each `ID` column value?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention I want them sorted based on the value. Where p1 has the highest value and p2 second highest etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crazy one-liner that does it:

```
head -1 file; tail -n+2 file| nl| sort -nrk4| awk '{ ++m[$3]; print($1" "$2" "$3"p"m[$3]" "$4); }'| sort -n| cut -d' ' -f2-4| column -to' ';
```

Output:

```
unique  ID  VALUE
A1  GENEAp1 10
A2  GENEAp2 5
A3  GENEAp3 2
A4  GENEBp4 4
A5  GENEBp3 5
A6  GENEBp2 8
A7  GENEBp1 70
A8  GENECp1 5
A9  GENEDp1 50
A10 GENEDp2 10
```

It involves sorting the file by the `VALUE` column, and then processing it sequentially in `awk`, counting occurrences of each distinct `ID` in an associative array, so you can build up the `p#` count.

Additional notes:

- I printed the header line (`head -1`) separately from the data lines (`tail -n+2`) so the main processing pipeline would only apply to the data lines.
- I added a call to `nl` before the initial `sort` to capture the original line order in a new leading numbering column, and then sorted by that column afterward (and then `cut` out that numbering column) to return to the original order.
- I added `column -to' '` at the end to align the data lines, don't know if you want/need that. If you want to align the header line with the data lines, you can surround the `head` statement and main pipeline with a braced block and move the `column -to' '` filter outside the braced block to align the whole thing.

Comment: Wow amazing those one-liners! I removed the "column -to' ';" because I was getting the error: 

`column: invalid option -- 'o'
usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]`

but without it it also works perfectly!